# Can an object be released in viewDidDisappear method?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to release the objects,which are used to design the User Interface ,mostly UILabel 's.Is it safe to release the label objects in the viewDidDisappear method as i navigate from one screen to another ?

and i am not using ARC.

Comment: if you allocated them manually - yes, if you created them in the Interface Builder - you might get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error if you try to access them later because labels might be deallocated

Comment: why not use dealloc method to release in non-ARC

Comment: I released it in dealloc, but after a while i get a "Out Of Memory Error." ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the release in `viewDidDisappear` there will be a lot of problems.

If you present a modal view from this parentView, the viewDidDisappear will be called, at that time crash will occur.

**The best place to release object in Non-ARC environment is the dealloc method.**

**If you are using iOS 5 or greater then the best choice is to enable ARC.**